# Get sum of rows in a single row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I'm getting data from a view like below structure

```
Column A        Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E
Platform Total  Plant A     Product A   Date        NULL
Platform 1      Plant A     Product A   Date        100
Platform 2      Plant A     Product A   Date        200
Platform Total  Plant B     Product B   Date        NULL
Platform 5      Plant B     Product B   Date        150
Platform 6      Plant B     Product B   Date        250
```

How can I get data in below format

```
Column A        Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E
Platform Total  Plant A     Product A   Date        300
Platform 1      Plant A     Product A   Date        100
Platform 2      Plant A     Product A   Date        200
Platform Total  Plant B     Product B   Date        400
Platform 5      Plant B     Product B   Date        150
Platform 6      Plant B     Product B   Date        250
```

That is, Column E should be Sum of values in Column E where Column A = 'Platform Total' and Column B and C are having same value. Tried with self join but not able to figure out.

Thanks for your time to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions and a conditional argument:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.e,
                sum(e) over (partition by t.b, t.c)
               ) as e
from t;
```

Actually, this just looks for the `null` value.  You want it set for a particular value in `a`:

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d,
       (case when t.a = 'Platform Total'
             then sum(t.e) over (partition by t.b, t.c)
             else t.e
        end) as e
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff..Partition is the exact way which I couldn't recollect, instead I was trying with CTE and self joins. You saved my day. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use UNION

```
SELECT A,B,C,D FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT 'Total',SUM(B),SUM(C),SUM(D) FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, Column E 
from table 
where ColumnA <> 'Platform Total' 
union all 
select 'Platform Total', ColumnB, ColumnC, max(ColumnD), sum(Column E) 
from table 
where ColumnA <> 'Platform Total'  
group by ColumnB, ColumnC
```